# Why am I getting a segmentation fault in my code? I can't debug it, explain the error

Tags: c

I don't know what is causing the problem, I get a "segmentation fault core dumped" after the for loop used for reading the input array is executed. The `printf("\nEntered array: ");` won't run. Please help me, usually we get a "segmentation fault" at the scanf statement but it looks like I get the error after my for loop completion. I added a `printf("%d", *(ptr+i));` statement after the scanf in the for loop to ensure this as it prints the entered value. But as soon as type enter after typing the last value for the array, I get this "segmentation fault core dumped".

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void main(){

    int n,temp;
    printf("Enter size of input array: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int *ptr = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    printf("\nEnter input array: ");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%d", (ptr+i));
        printf("%d\n", *(ptr+i));
    }
    printf("\nEntered array: ");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%d ", *(ptr+i));
    for(int j=1;j<n;j++){
        temp = *(ptr+j);
        for(int i = j - 1;i>0;i++){
            if(temp < *(ptr+i)){
                *(ptr+i+1) = *(ptr+i);
                *(ptr+i) = temp;
            }
            else{
                break;  
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\nSorted  array: ");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%d ", *(ptr+i));
    printf("\n");
}
```

Output in Termminal:

```
chirag@abhishek-HP-Laptop-15q-dy0xxx:~/chirag_C/algorithms$ ./insertionsort
Enter size of input array: 3

Enter input array: 3 2 1
3
2
1

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
chirag@abhishek-HP-Laptop-15q-dy0xxx:~/chirag_C/algorithms$
```

Please undelete my question, I have added the full code with it's output.

Comment: This "for(int i = j - 1;i>0;i++)"   sets i = 0  and increments forever since the stop condition is  "i > 0."   Let us know if that fixes it

Comment: The correct return type for `main` is `int`, not `void`.

Comment: OT: hint: instead of `*(ptr+i)` you should write `ptr[i]`. It's exactly the same thing but it's much more readable.

Comment: Since your loop condition is "i > 0", you should make "i--" instead of "i++" and i think your condition should be "i >= 0".

Comment: use valgrind you will get your invalid write, for example `ptr+i+1`